# Is it okay/valid to have a Bode plot that has linear magnitude scale?

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

I have almost always seen that the magnitude axis of a Bode plot is in dB but today I was shocked when I saw in LTspice that Linear option was also available for Bode representation.

I am very confused. Is it okay/valid to have a Bode plot that has linear magnitude scale rather magnitude scale in dB?

As shown highlighted in attached photo:

[image]

Comment: I think you might also be able to set the frequency axis (x-axis) to linear, as well. I don't think any of this is advisable. There may be some arcane reason, though. My guess is that since you can perform functions on the curve in LTspice then in some cases a linear display would make more sense. But not as a general rule.

Comment: It's OK. In some contexts it's confusing, and it's incapable of showing you anything below about -50dB, which is why log is usually preferred. But it's not fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I think in order for this question to be answerable, you'd need to define what "okay" means to you. It goes without saying it's not _illegal_ and presumably you also understand it's not fundamentally incorrect. Maybe what you meant to ask is "is there a scenario where a linear magnitude scale is useful, which could explain why LTSpice offers it?"

Comment: @user_1818839 But is it even a **Bode Plot** anymore if the magnitude is not in dB?